# Analogue of localStorage & sessionStorage for .chm file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chm, ie8-compatibility-mode

So, I'm looking for something similar to local/session storages for .chm file.
I've tried to google it, really, but totally failed.

Any ideas, suggestions, links would be very helpful.

Comment: Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: CHM is like a compiled (zipped) web site putting together all files. Do you want to compile special HTML5 topics with LocaleStorage into a new CHM?